# t4 toolbox - Preprocessed template - Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

Tags: t4-toolbox

I have been using T4Toolbox with the custom tool '`TextTemplatingFileGenerator`' and everything has been working great.

Recently, I have been in the process of trying to start using preprocessed templates (i.e., with the `TextTemplatingFilePreProcessor` custom tool property setting). 
I added the TextTemplating and `TextTemplating.Interfaces` references. I included a copy of the T4Toolbox.dll in my local solution and referenced it as well.

To try to help simplify this question, I reduced the content of my TextTemplate1.tt template content to the following few lines:

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension="txt" #>
<#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #>
```

The issue that I'm having is I get the following error when I include the `T4Toolbox.tt` file:

`T4TooboxPreProcessedTemplates.TextTemplate1.Dispose(bool)` : no suitable method found to override

Can someone help me get past this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got past this by using the T4 Toolbox / Template item instead of the TextTemplate item. There is still an issue with the TextTransformation.Host being null but I posted a new question to address that.